# CAPL associative array with string types

Tags: string, associative-array, capl

Following this [paper](https://kb.vector.com/upload_551/file/CAPL_3_CANNewsletter_201411_PressArticle_EN.pdf), I'm trying to create an associative array like this:

```
variables
{
  char[30] translate[ char[] ];
}
```

It is exactly the same example in the paper. Problem comes when I try to put values to this associative array. For example:

```
on preStart
{
  translate["hello"] = "hola";
}
```

That gives me a compilation error: "Error     1112 at (89,23): **operand types are incompatible**"

What I'm doing wrong?

VERSIONS: I'm using **Vector CAPL Browser** included with **CANalyzer version 11.0** SP2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With associative fields (so-called maps) you can perform a 1:1 assignment of values to other values without using excessive memory. The elements of an associative field are key value pairs, whereby there is fast access to a value via a key.

An associative field is declared in a similar way to a normal field but the data type of the key is written in square brackets:

```
int m[float];         // maps floats to ints
float x[int64];       // maps int64s to floats
char[30] s[ char[] ]  // maps strings (of unspecified length) to strings of length < 30
```

If the key type **char[]** is specified, all the character fields (of any size) can be used as key values. In the iteration the loop variable must then also be declared as **char[]**. Key comparisons, e.g. in order to determine iteration sequence, are then performed as character string comparisons, whereby no country-specific algorithms are used.

**char[]** is the only field type that can be used as a key type. Please bear in mind that you can not declare variables or parameters of the **char[]** type, with the exception of loop variables in the iteration.

**Association between strings:**

```
char[30] namen[char []];
strncpy(namen["Max"], "Mustermann", 30); 
strncpy(namen["Vector"], "Informatik", 30);

for (char[] mykey : namen)
{
  write("%s is mapped to %s", mykey, namen[mykey]);
}
```

Comment: With the Vector CAPL Browser Version 11.0.55.0, compiling gives me a "Parse error"

Comment: You can only initialize a char array once, when it is declared, and initialization is the only circumstance in which you can populate an array.
Do not confuse initialization with assignment.
In the current context, the association between strings can be done as specified in the example: 
strncpy(namen["Vector"], "Informatik", 30);