# CAPL associative array with message type

Tags: capl, canoe, automotive, canalyzer

I'm trying to make CAPL associative array which could hold e.g. 10 most recent CAN messages for each ID like below:

```
message[10] messages[long]
```

Is there possibility to make associative array in CAPL, where key would be some integral type value, and value would be array of messages?

Comment: There is nothing called as associating table in CAPL. What is your use case here?

Comment: It's called associative arrays. Have a look here e.g.: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55207365/4866709)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the indication - changed the name of it. Use case is to store most recent messages with unique CAN IDs in order to pass it to external script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data type `message` is an object. Since only "simple data types" are possible, you cannot declare a `message` variable with associative fields.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://blog.csdn.net/qq_34414530/article/details/126055577 the data types of key and value can be: long, int64, float, double, enumeration types and char[]. In that case you can not declare an associative array with key of data type message.

Comment: Could you add an English language link to your answer? The link you posted is in Chinese. In general, prefer original documentation links when you can because there is a possibility any other link/post may get deleted in future. Thank you

Comment: Hi Anon. The original post is in Chinese, it seems that it is a blog from Ant Minion. I could not find an English version and also I can not Chinese. I just used the translator in the web browser (Chrome). Thank you